# Google Analitycs - Demographics

Tags: google-analytics

I just turn on demography, copy and insert tracking code in my head tags,
it showing when i use page but not show my gender and age,
it's need time ?

[online users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geQid.png)
[demography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/087a6.png)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Demographics data do not work in this way, they do not represent 100% of users and require reaching a certain threshold of data to be displayed.

Demographics and interests data may only be available for a subset of your users, and may not represent the overall composition of your traffic: Analytics cannot collect the demographics and interests information if the DoubleClick cookie or the Device Advertising ID is not present, or if no activity profile is included.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en

Example with test: https://www.analyticstraps.com/i-report-con-i-dati-demografici-non-tornano/